# ExpressJS Cors not working from Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, express

I'm trying to get my Express Server working, but I keep getting the following error:

```
Failed to load http://localhost:3000/api/todos: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.
```

From all my search results, people keep saying add the headers ( which I did ) or do `app.use(cors())` but both gave me the same result.

this is my **app.js**

```
const app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/api/todos', require('./routes/todos.route').todos);

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", '*');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", 'Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,content-type,application/json');
    next();
});

mongoose.Promise = bluebird;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/mean-app2')
    .then(() => {
        console.log(`Succesfully Connected to the Mongodb Database  at URL : mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/mean-app2`)
    })
    .catch(() => {
        console.log(`Error Connecting to the Mongodb Database at URL : mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/mean-app2`)
    });

module.exports = app;
```

As you can see all the headers are set, and origin should allow all connections. But still no luck, and this drives me nuts!

Greetings Glenn

Comment: Did you add `app.use(cors())` or the headers before your route declarations?In the example i find them below your route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the CORS settings before your route declaration.
Whatever settings you want apply on routes must be declared before the route declarations.

```
    const app = express();

    // view engine setup
    app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

    // uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
    //app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
    app.use(logger('dev'));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
    app.use(cookieParser());
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

   app.use(function(req, res, next) {
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", '*');
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", 'Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,content-type,application/json');
        next();
    });
    app.use('/api/todos', require('./routes/todos.route').todos);



    mongoose.Promise = bluebird;
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/mean-app2')
        .then(() => {
            console.log(`Succesfully Connected to the Mongodb Database  at URL : mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/mean-app2`)
        })
        .catch(() => {
            console.log(`Error Connecting to the Mongodb Database at URL : mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/mean-app2`)
        });

    module.exports = app;
```